# OpenWRT Samba Share

Tags: samba, openwrt

When I try to mount my router's samba share with

```
$ sudo mount.cifs //192.168.1.1/sda1 /mnt/hd2  -o guest
```

I get the error,

```
mount error(2): No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because it's trying Samba 3.0 and my server doesn't support,

```
$ sudo mount.cifs //router/sda1 /mnt/hd2  -o vers=2.0,guest,vers=3.0
mount error(2): No such file or directory
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs) and kernel log messages (dmesg)
$ sudo mount.cifs //router/sda1 /mnt/hd2  -o vers=2.0,guest,vers=2.0
```

I just needed vers=2.0